# redirect modifies {REQUEST_URI} so that php does not get urldecoded information

Tags: php, .htaccess, urldecode

I have a .htaccess file to redirect http requests to https.  When a link that includes urlencoded data is processed by the file, the subsequent data delivered to my php script does not get urldedoded data when accessed using the $_REQUEST array.  Here is the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Specifically one of the fields entered is an email address and it is encoded as em=someone%40gmail.com and that is exactly what my php script gets from the $_REQUEST["em"] variable.  This is supposed to be decoded data and without the redirect it is correct, but after the redirect is inserted, the data is not decoded.  Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong??  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NE [NoEscape](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) flag in your Rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https: //%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.